# fx module is not getting resolved in Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am very new to dojo. Trying the basic example given in the documentation. This is my code

```
<body>
    <h1 id="greeting">Hello</h1>

    <!-- configure Dojo -->
    <script>
        var dojoConfig = {
            async: true
        }
    </script>

    <!-- load Dojo -->
    <script src="/public/dojo.js"></script>

    <script>
        require([
            'dojo/fx',
            'dojo/dom',
            'dojo/domReady!'
        ], function (fx, dom) {
            // The piece we had before...
            var greeting = dom.byId('greeting');
            greeting.innerHTML += ' from Dojo!';

            // ...but now, with an animation!
            fx.slideTo({
                node: greeting,
                top: 100,
                left: 200
            }).play();
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

I am using node server for serving the static assets. The error popping is

> GET http://localhost:3000/public/fx.js net::ERR_ABORTED

I couldn't figure out the reason why its looking for a separate file fx.js here?

If I change that line to this

```
require([
            'dojo/_base/fx',
            'dojo/dom',
            'dojo/domReady!'
        ]
```

This time its not looking for the separate file from _base/fx.js.

Please help me on this.

**EDIT**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>
```

Instead of serving from locally if I refer from the cdn its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the reason,

If i require fx module

```
 require([
            'dojo/fx',
            'dojo/dom',
            'dojo/dom-construct',
            'dojo/domReady!'
        ]
```

with this cdn link

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

When I see the network requests the script internally triggers a request to this url

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/fx.js
```

So it works without any error. In my local setup the file (fx.js) is missing. So the error occurs. Since in the example it is mentioned only one URL link that points to dojo.js I downloaded only that file and missed to put this fx.js file.